# Are both versions natural?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, writing

Are both versions natural?

1.

He came out onto the roof with a bottle of whisky in his hand. **He was about to take a gulp from it when it slipped out of his hand and shattered.**

2.

He came out onto the roof with a bottle of whisky in his hand. **About to take a gulp from it, it slipped out of his hand and shattered.**

Answer (score 1):

The first option sounds far more natural.

The construction used in the second option is used when the first part of the sentence is the cause of the second part.

For example, "About to be captured, he decided running away was the best option."

The capturing is both imminent and the reason for the decision.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is fine.

The problem with the second one is that the first phrase modifies the *it* after the comma, but you really need it to modify *he*. "*It* was about to take a gulp from it(self)" is what it strictly means. If you said something like this instead, it would be okay:

> About to take a gulp from it, **he** dropped it and watched as it shattered.

Everyone would know what you meant, though, and it's a relatively common mistake to use when speaking informally, so it's not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

Both sound natural, but feel different.

If the police showed-up, and demanded to know why there was broken glass on the ground, you might answer like the first sentence.  It's very factual-sounding; clear about the agent, beginning/end, sequence of events.

The second one is more a telling of a story.  It starts to suggest a larger context; perhaps some other agenct is at work (destiny, fate, etc.); and that something will happen next.  Stylistically, it invites more questions in the way an author might draw-in a listener / reader.  In J. R. R. Tolkien's 'Lord of the Rings' story, he uses a style like this to talk about the ring -- how it, or destiny, causes it to become lost or found.